# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start actvity ComponentInfo(com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity)

Tags: android, android-activity

### I am trying to run Simple app that call another activity But Having error that i am unable to solve. I am new to here and for android also. please help. Thank you.

```
06-02 23:08:18.863: W/dalvikvm(4388): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab7228)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{40df5418 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{40df5418 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1195)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4548)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
06-02 23:08:18.883: E/AndroidRuntime(4388):     ... 11 more
```

### MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) 
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment 
    {
        public PlaceholderFragment()
        {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
    
    public void sendMessage(View view)
    {   // Called when user clicks the send button
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

### DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
        
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);
        setContentView(textView);
        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

### fragment_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:hint="@string/edit_message"
              android:layout_weight="1" />
    
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

### ActivityMain.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Comment: post `activity_display_message.xml`

Comment: In your DisplayMessageActivity you are setting the contentview two times. I suppose you are trying to display the message in its fragment, so use the fragment factory pattern to pass the message to the fragment and declare the textview to show the message in the fragment layout. http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html

Comment: post activity_main.xml also. Also remove unwanted code. The manifest is not necessary. Also do not use setContentView twice for the same activtiy. bad design

Answer (score 2):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id
>   0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp:id/container) for fragment
>   PlaceholderFragment{40df5418 #0 id=0x7f05003c}

Looks like activity layout does not have a `ViewGroup` with id container. Generally its a `FrameLayout` which acts as a container to which you add/replace fragments.

Also do not have  `setContentView` twice for the activity.

Answer (score 1):

Check fragment_display_message.xml for warning.
In my case there was extra "/>" present which cause system unable to find view.
Once I removed and ran again, app launched.